# How to import apache poi library in android studio?

Tags: java, android, excel, android-studio, apache-poi

I want to make an android app that can read, write, and update different sheets in an excel workbook. But I can't include the library in android studio. please help. If any other library provides similar functionality, please do mention it.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android ?

Comment: You might be interested in [Spire.XLS for Android via Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-android-via-java.html) library, download it and you will find a series of demos for reading and manipulating Excel files. But note that it's a paid library.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
       repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
...
}

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2'
```